# creating a custom left tab to magento admin customer pages

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create an left tab to magento backend customer page.

I tried to add a module i found. but it doesnt work for `Magento 1.9` version.

here's the [LINK](http://mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/)

Comment: put your code thus we can check.

Comment: added module link.

Comment: is config.xml path location is Mydons/Customertab/etc or  Mydons/etc.1st one is right location

Comment: have you checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are issue with

**Issue:** Mydons_Customertab.xml  file <`codepool>` syntex should be 
and

**Issue2:** `config.xml` path location should be  `Mydons/Customertab/etc`

Comment: made those correction. Its working now. Thanks.